# I am not able to understand this pymongo error

Tags: python, pymongo

I was again working with my Pymongo file (really sorry I am asking soo many questions I am really new to pymongo.) and I get this error.. Could you explain what this means becuase I am really new...

```
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python_projects\Jeli-Bot\cogs\warns.py", line 36, in warn
    if collection.count_documents({"memberid":id}) == 0:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1827, in count_documents
    return self.__database.client._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1525, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, secondary_ok)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1821, in _cmd
    result = self._aggregate_one_result(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1686, in _aggregate_one_result
    result = self._command(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 238, in _command
    return sock_info.command(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 726, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 710, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 121, in command
    request_id, msg, size, max_doc_size = message._op_msg(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 743, in _op_msg
    return _op_msg_uncompressed(
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <property object at 0x000001AA06B13AE0>, of type: <class 'property'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to copy-paste the chunk of code you are running, also details on what you were trying to accomplish.

With the information provided I would think you are trying to pass an object to a function that shouldn't be receiving one.

Answer (score 0):

When you try and run a pymongo operation, the data you pass to the operation must match defined python types that pymongo understands. The values it understands are represented in the table here: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html

Your issue is that you passing a type that isn't in the `Python Type` column of the above link. For example, maybe you're passing a set, a datetime.date or an arbitrary class object. If this is the case, you will get the `InvalidDocument: cannot encode` error you are seeing.

Double check the document structure you are passing into the pymongo command.